# Undefined Index in __isset

Tags: php

I am getting an error in my actual code inside __isset, but when I went to a 'run php online website' it works. So I am not sure why it does not work in my code.

```
<?
class Test {

    private $args;

    public function __construct($args = array()) {
        $this->args = $args;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return $this->args[$name]; //undefined index on my server (is fine on php site)
    }

    function prnt() {
        // echo isset($this->i) ? "set" : "notset"; --> works, both print 'set'
        echo isset($this->h) ? "set" : "notset";
    }

}
?>
```

I then execute this:

```
$test = new Test(array('i' => '1234'));
$test->prnt();
//result on php website: notset
//result on my website: Undefined index at the line shown above.
```

Possibly helpful information:
My server is running php 5.1.
The `isset($this->var)` is happening in an `include` file in my actual code.
As long as the variable exists (like `i` above) it obviously works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error reporting settings in each environment are different. One environment is allowing errors of `E_NOTICE` level through while another is blocking them.

You should do something like this:

```
return array_key_exists($name, $this->args);
```

Comment: Thanks for including the actual difference between them.

Comment: The same answer at (almost) the same time makes it hard to choose an answer. =p I like the error reporting explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to return the value of a non existent key, instead return the result of testing for the key using `array_key_exists`

```
public function __isset($name) {
    return array_key_exists($name, $this->args);
}
```

Comment: Well that is an easy fix. Thank you.